# Looking for advice on my unit test case logic c# console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, console-application

I sort of just wanted to have my code reviewed for logical purposes.  I think it works out the way I expect it to but I'd like to double check with peers who are more versed in C#.

So here I am testing a console application which validates user input.  I am using StringReader to simulate the user response.  So I entered in 5 as my response and if my response is not a valid float then I should receive an error.

I tested this against a non-float value and my for loop caused me to enter a insufficient memory exception which makes sense.  But for some reason in my test, I feel like I'm writing to my Input1() function and just validating that my input was indeed the value that i simulated?  Or is my test actually validating that the return value of Input1() is actually num1 in the form of a float - thus passing my validation?

Sorry if this is overkill and not making sense.

```
    public float Input1()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Type a number, and then press Enter");
        bool Valid = false;
        while (Valid == false)
        {
            //bad implementation here: Input = Input;
            String Input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Input);
            if (!float.TryParse(Input, out Number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer, please try again.");
            }
            else
            {
                Valid = true;
                num1 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(Input);
            }
        }
        return num1;
    }


[Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var calc = new CalculatorApp.Program();
        var output = new StringWriter();
        float num1;
        float expectedresult;
        Console.SetOut(output);
        var input = new StringReader("5");
        Console.SetIn(input);

        calc.Input1();
        //num1 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(output);

        Assert.That(output.ToString(), Is.EqualTo(string.Format("5\r\n", Environment.NewLine)));
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: If* statement.  not For loop.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there are a few points to your question. First, let's clean up the code a bit:

```
public float GetNumberFromUser()
{
    float result;
    while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number...");
    }
    return result;
}
```

This isn't so much a unit test as it is an integration test. Typically in unit testing, you're testing the logic of a specific class or method. In this case, you're pulling in external libraries and testing them as well.

In this case, a negative test is not going to work. The test will end up in an infinite loop, and as you've seen, will eventually run out of memory.

If you really want to test something like this, and probably the answer you're looking for, you're better off using dependency injection and creating a wrapper class and mocking the library calls. This way you have better control over the flow of the test.

It looks as if you might be trying to learn Test Driven Development. I encourage you to read up on things that need testing and things that don't. Many people get carried away when they start doing unit tests and look for 100% code coverage with positive testing, negative testing, mocking too much, and even external library testing. This level of testing isn't typically needed. Test when it makes sense.

As an aside, you should not call GC.Collect in that situation. Garbage collection is handled for you in .NET and there are very few reasons to ever use that method.

Comment: Thank you Skyhawk.  Watching a tut on Dependency injection now.  Will try to apply to my code.  But basically DI is to make my code decoupled right?  The tests I am running will still execute the same as they are now?  I will still only be able to test the positive test - and will not be able to test the negative.  The DI is just for better programming practices right?

Comment: Yes, it's mainly used for decoupling, and tends to make unit testing easier and cleaner. It's a topic that pretty much every developer should learn and understand.